# What’s the point of voting to close for “Needs details or clarity” without telling the author what detail or clarity it needs?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[**Posting in question**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/261577/668)

Apparently 4 people have voted to close this, but not one of them thought to leave a comment.

Let’s say it gets another vote and gets closed. What do you expect the author to do? Take a guess at what detail you thought was missing and resubmit? What about the already submitted answers?

I’m really not sure I understand the logic here.

Comment: I don't think the challenge needs more details, but the fact that it doesn't have as defined of a specification than other challenges would put people off. But for a challenge that is pretty obvious like this, I don't think its a problem.